# Terraform - Unable to pass string variable to child module

Tags: terraform, terraform-aws-modules

I have terraform setup with a number of nested modules. Simplified it looks like this

```
├── modules
│   ├── sec-groups
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   ├── variables.tf
│   │   └── versions.tf
├── dev
│   ├── env.dev.tfvars
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── versions.tf
│   └── variables.tf
└── prod
    ├── env.prod.tfvars
    ├── main.tf
    ├── versions.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

**Where in dev:**

main.tf

```
module "aws_dev_sec-groups" {
  source = "../modules/sec-groups"

  vpc_name   = aws_vpc.dev_bp_vpc
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.dev_bp_vpc.id

  localip  = var.localip
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "localip" {
  type = string
}
```

env.dev.tfvars

```
localip = "1.1.1.1/32"
```

**And in the sec-groups module:**

main.tf

```
resource "aws_security_group" "servers_sg" {
  name = "servers_sg"
  description = "Traffic allowed to and from Servers"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [var.localip]
  }
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable vpc_id {}
variable localip {
  type = string
}
```

--

'terraform init' produces expected results. However, 'terraform plan' produces the following error. To me this suggests an empty localip variable, which means I'm not correctly declaring the variable, is this the case?

```
Error: "" is not a valid CIDR block: invalid CIDR address:

  on ../modules/sec-groups/main.tf line 63, in resource "aws_security_group" "servers_sg":
  63: resource "aws_security_group" "servers_sg" {
  }
```

Thanks in advance

--

```
% terraform -v
    Terraform v0.13.0
    + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.2.0
    + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v2.3.0
```

Comment: I don't think that `env.dev.tfvars` is automatically loaded into variables. Either rename the file to `env.dev.auto.tfvars` or specify it on the command line using the `-var-file="env.dev.tfvars"` argument when doing terraform plan & apply.

Comment: The above comment is correct but you should instead get an error about the `localip` variable not being set because it doesn't contain a default value in the root module `vars.tf`. Have you mangled things slightly and removed this? Or is this code exactly an [mcve]?

Comment: The title is very very misleading... you can pass the variable just fine _ _ _ look in your code where is that `""` set for the variable

Comment: When I call plan, I specify `-var-file=env.dev.auto.tfvars` using 'auto' doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda - I don't understand why the title is misleading. I have specified the variable as '1.1.1.1' and as far as I can tell it is not bring passed to the module. Is there a better way to describe this

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - you're right. When I pull the specific code out of the bigger programme and run it independently, the plan executes as expected. So it's something within the wider set of modules that is breaking this. I will build the code back up a bit at a time to see if I can identify the code that is causing it to break. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I has completely miss-understood how modules work. I assumed that submodules needed to use variables from the parent or other submodules by specifying multiple module blocks within the submodule. I found I was passing variables from multiple submodules to every submodule, which seems odd in hindsight but didn't at the time.

This meant some submodules were trying to re-instantiate multiple times, in a loop, hence the error messages. I now realise the beast approach is for the parent module to call the output values of submodules to pass to other submodules and that submodules should not reference one another using the same variables as those in the parent module.

Thanks for all the pointers with this, apologies for the red-herring reference the localip variable.

Answer (score 0):

Variables from a `.tfvars` file are assigned to the root module.

If the code you posted is actually at root level, it will work, when you specify the `-var-file`.

If it is not actually at root level, you are most likely not passing down the `localip` var correctly. The fact that you see `Error: "" is not a valid CIDR block: invalid CIDR address:` indicates that you are passing down an empty string somewhere. If you would not load the `.tfvars` correctly and the code above is actually at root level, you would get a different error (missing variable), since you did not provide a default to the `localip` variable.